Custom matcher in vitest exception: Failure cause not provided for
I'm using Vitest and I wrote simple custom matcher in my setup file:
import { expect } from 'vitest';

expect.extend({
   aaa: (received: number, expected: number) => {
       const pass = received === expected;
       if (pass) {
           return {
               message: () => `expected ${received} not to be ${expected}`,
               pass: true,
           };
       } else {
           return {
               message: () => `expected ${received} to be ${expected}`,
               pass: false,
           };
       }
   }
})

I'm using it in sample test:
it('should aaa', () => {
      // @ts-ignore
       expect(3).aaa(2);
   });

When given correct expected and received values, test passes correctly. But when (as in above example) values does not match, test instead of failing with given message, throws error:
Failure cause not provided for 'should aaa'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
